# Is it safe to assume pid_t is always an int type (as defined in the standard)?

Tags: c, macos, compare-and-swap

I wanted to atomically compare and swap pid_t variable. I read in standard it is int type.

I know as a matter of atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit() can manage things on its own. All I need to do is set type as _Atomic(pid_t).

But as I am working on macOS and I want to make it compatible with OSX old library as well which is [libkern/OSAtomic.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32.3.html) that would need to know the type and size of the type to CAS it.

Like in case of size_t I could simply do like,

```
#   ifdef __LP64__
#       define CAS_size_t(old, new, mem) \
        OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64((int64_t) (*old), (int64_t) (new), (volatile int64_t *) (mem))
#   else
#       define CAS_size_t(old, new, mem) \
        OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32((int32_t) (*old), (int32_t) (new), (volatile int32_t *) (mem))
#   endif
```

But in case of pid_t I am not sure because even if `__LP64__` is not defined then it can be int64_t, int32_t, int16_t or something?

Comment: All you know is that it's some signed integer type which is capable of representing a process ID. You could have `#if` cases based on the value of `sizeof(pid_t)`, and throw a compile error in the `#else` case.

Comment: Probably `sizeof(pid_t)` won’t work in #if condition right. Its preprocessed?

Comment: Right, I had forgotten that

Comment: Do you have C11? You could go with _Generic solution. Or just pass `sizeof(var)` to the function... Why not just a simple `#define CAS_size_t(old, new, mem) do { if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int64_t)) { call_64(...); } else if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int32_t)) { call_32(...); } else assert(0); } while(0)`. The chek will probably be optimized out by the compiler anyway.

Comment: Well for C11, stdatomic.h is already a solution, but the main goal is to make it backward compatible too. Probably I need to stick with a function in that case. Also thanks for sharing that `_Generic` thing, I didn’t knew about that.

Comment: @KamilCuk, wellll you are right. Thanks for that too, it didn’t hit my mind at all before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the sizeof of the value inside the macro:

```
#define OSAtomicCompareAndSwap(old, new, mem)  do{ \
     if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int32_t)) { \
        OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32((int32_t)(*old), (int32_t) (new), (volatile int32_t *) (mem));  \
     } else if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int64_t)) { \
        OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64((int64_t)(*old), (int64_t) (new), (volatile int64_t *) (mem));  \
     } else assert(0); }while(0)
```

The checks should be optimized out by the compiler anyway. It's not type checking (for that we would need C++-ish typeid), only the size is checked.

If you need to return a value, if think you'll need to pass another variable:

```
#define OSAtomicCompareAndSwap(ret, old, new, mem)  do{ \
     if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int32_t)) { \
        ret = OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32((int32_t)(*old), (int32_t) (new), (volatile int32_t *) (mem));  \
     } else if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int64_t)) { \
        ret = OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64((int64_t)(*old), (int64_t) (new), (volatile int64_t *) (mem));  \
     } else assert(0); }while(0)
```

or ex. pass a pointer to a variable to be memcpy-ied with the result or such. Or you could use [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) gcc extension.

With a statement expression that could look like:

```
#define OSAtomicCompareAndSwap(old, new, mem)  __extension__({ \
     int64_t ret = 0; \
     if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int32_t)) { \
        ret = OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32((int32_t)(*old), (int32_t) (new), (volatile int32_t *) (mem));  \
     } else if (sizeof(*old) == sizeof(int64_t)) { \
        ret = OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64((int64_t)(*old), (int64_t) (new), (volatile int64_t *) (mem));  \
     } else { \
          assert(0); \
     } \
     ret; \
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. That `statement expression` extension sure will be a lot of help to me, great to know so much in a single post.

Comment: you should define the macros without the trailing ';' because you would write a ";" after a macro call anyway. The way it is now, this wouldn't compile: `if( .. ) OSAtomicCompareAndSwap(old,new,mem);else ...`